# How to avoid running window after its size scaled to the minimal size?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

The main window has a minimal width, height and an aspect ratio via `NSSize` However when the window scale to the minimal size, it would start to running downwards on the screen if the resizing event keep triggering from the top or right window corner.

Is there any window property have been missed here?

```
let contentView = ContentView()
    .frame(minWidth: 120, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

/// Create the window and set the content view.
window = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 50),
    styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false, onKeyDown: handleKeyDownEvent)

window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
window.contentView?.window?.aspectRatio = NSSize(
    width: 120,
    height: 50
)
```

Tried prevent the window from resizing via the window delegate method, `windowWillResize(_:to:)` [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419292-windowwillresize) but the window still running around when it get squeezed.

Also tried to use `windowWillMove(_:)` [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419336-windowwillmove) to print the window position and with an intension to stop it from moving. However, the position changed by squeezing the window wont be captured in the debug console.

[image]

Comment: It is something in those DC* things.

Comment: its just `EmptyView()` and `DCWindow` is `NSWindow`'s subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
window.contentView?.window?.aspectRatio = NSSize(
    width: 120,
    height: 50
)
```

A better approach to make window resize in proportion is to do it inside `windowWillResize(_:to:)` an `NSWindowDelegate` method. Don't forget to set the `window.delegate` if you set up all user interface programmatically.

```
extension AppDelegate: NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowWillResize(_ sender: NSWindow, to frameSize: NSSize) -> NSSize {
        return CGSize(width: frameSize.height * SOME_RATIO, height: frameSize.height)
    }
}
```